Creating a Custom Node for Materials through Python
I'm trying to create a custom material node in blender using python.
For instance, in the example below (which I found here and modified a bit):
The node is supposed to take two colors multiply them together and output and emission shader with the result.
import bpy
from bpy.types import Node

class MultiplierNode(Node):
    '''This is a custom node that multiplies two inputs and outputs the result.'''

    bl_idname = 'MultiplierNode' # Unique identifier for your node type
    bl_label = 'Multiplier' # Display name for your node

    def init(self, context):
        # This method is called when the node is created
        maincolor = self.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor', 'Main Color')
        maincolor.default_value = [1, 0.5, 0.75, 1]

        subcolor = self.inputs.new('NodeSocketColor', 'Sub Color')
        subcolor.default_value = [0.63, 0.27, 1, 1]

        emission = self.outputs.new('NodeSocketShader', 'Emission')
    
    def update(self):
        # This method is called when the node updates
        # the node should output the shader but NodeSocketShader doesn't have a default_value attribute or any method to pass the data to the shader output
        self.outputs[0].default_value = self.inputs[0].default_value * self.inputs[1].default_value

# Register your node type with Blender
bpy.utils.register_class(MultiplierNode)

I'd really appreciate it, if someone gave wrote a more advanced working example and explain it to me, as I've been trying to get this to work for a long time now.
Note: I know I could've used osl for this, but osl only works with cycles and I want the node to work with Eevee which this method basically satisfy and blender unfortunately doesn't support glsl external scripts anymore.

The python defined shader nodes have no benefits over node groups. Just make a .blend file with a node group and import from there.

@unwave you're right in most cases, but in some special cases it's better. Like in my case, I'm creating a custom shader not a node group.

They do not work without the addon that defines them. The UI features do not worth that. If you already have to use the addon it can have the "do good" button on its own. And the example in your question is for Geometry Nodes.

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/is-there-a-way-to-create-custom-node-types-or-nodes-categories-using-python/33215/5
